# Heatmap.js Just want a red blob not multiple colours on the datapoint

Tags: javascript, heatmap

I have created a heatmap and I just want my data point to be one colour instead of multiple colors like the standard one is, I'm not sure how to change the configuration of all the data points to do this.

I basically just want the colour in the middle to be the colour of the entire circle.

https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-heatmap-googlemaps.html

On that website you will see an example of a heatmap and the data points all have blue bits around the outside I literally just want to make my points so they are just the colour in the middle of the data point.

For example the point in Florida I just want that entire circle to be red because it is red in the middle, instead of having the blue/yellow/green bits.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define the gradient in the `heatmap` and also set the blur value to cero:

For example:

```
var config = {
  container: document.querySelector('.heatmap'),
  blur: 0,
  gradient: {
    '1': 'red',
    '0': 'white',
  },
};
var heatmapInstance = h337.create(config);
```